# VBA Run-Time Error '1004': can't paste because area not the same

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to de-bug some VBA code and haven't been able to hit on the right terms. I'm attempting to copy multiple rows and columns from multiple sheets into one master sheet. I know the issue is that I'm seleting too large of an area to copy and paste, but could use some help refining the code to only select and paste the data I need. Any help appreciated!

What I have now:

```vba
Sub OpenXML()
'
'Use this macro to open XML 2003 docs and save them as XLSX and combine them into one XLSX doc
'

Dim wbTemp, wbSave As Workbook
Dim count As Long
Dim xmlFilePath, saveFilePath, fileName As String

Set wbSave = Workbooks.Add
count = 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'======>>>____Update file paths here____<<<======
xmlFilePath = [withheld]
saveFilePath = [withheld]

file = Dir(xmlFilePath & "*.xml")
fileNameNoExt = Left(file, Len(file) - 4)

'Loop to open the XML file, save a copy as XLSX, AND create a combined file with all data
Do While Len(file) > 0
    'Open each XML file
    Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=xmlFilePath & file)
    'Save as XLSX
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=saveFilePath & fileNameNoExt & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    
    'Copy data from each XML into one main XLSX
    wbTemp.Sheets(2).Select
    If count = 1 Then 'take only 1 header row
        Rows("1:1").Select
    Else
        Rows("2:2").Select
    End If
    
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy wbSave.Sheets(1).Cells(count, 1)
    wbTemp.Close
    count = wbSave.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.count + 1
    
    'Prep for next file
    file = Dir
    If Len(file) > 0 Then
        fileNameNoExt = Left(file, Len(file) - 4)
    End If
Loop

wbSave.SaveAs fileName:=saveFilePath & "AllSheetsCombined.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
wbSave.Close

End Sub
```

I tried something similar to

```vba
   Sub SelectRangeDown()
      Range("c1", Range("c1").End(xlDown)).Select
   End Sub
```

but did did not work

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [UsedRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.usedrange)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub OpenXML()
    '
    'Use this macro to open XML 2003 docs and
    'save them as XLSX and combine them into one XLSX doc
    
    '======>>>____Update file paths here____<<<======
    Const xmlFilePath = "" '[withheld]
    Const saveFilePath = "" '[withheld]"
    Const xmlsheet = 2
    
    Dim wbTemp As Workbook, wbSave As Workbook
    Dim rngSource As Range, rngTarget As Range
    Dim fileName As String, fileNameNoExt As String
    Dim h As Long, n As Long
    
    Set wbSave = Workbooks.Add
    Set rngTarget = wbSave.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
    
    'Loop to open the XML file, save a copy as XLSX,
    ' AND create a combined file with all data
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    h = 0 ' header offset
    fileName = Dir(xmlFilePath & "*.xml")
    Do While Len(fileName) > 0
        fileNameNoExt = Left(fileName, Len(fileName) - 4)
        'Open each XML file
        Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=xmlFilePath & fileName, ReadOnly:=True)
        With wbTemp
            
            'Copy data from each XML into one main XLSX
            With .Sheets(xmlsheet).UsedRange
                Set rngSource = .Offset(h).Resize(.Rows.count - h)
                rngSource.Copy rngTarget
                Set rngTarget = rngTarget.Offset(rngSource.Rows.count)
            End With
            
            'Save as XLSX
            .SaveAs fileName:=saveFilePath & fileNameNoExt & ".xlsx", _
                    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
            .Close
             
        End With
             
        ' next file
        h = 1 ' no header after first file
        n = n + 1
        fileName = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    wbSave.SaveAs fileName:=saveFilePath & "AllSheetsCombined.xlsx", _
                  FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    wbSave.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    MsgBox n & " files combined", vbInformation

End Sub
```